# compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion file's location?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I cant find out which compileSdkVersion I am using. neither i can find the file in which it is defined.
`compileSdkVersion: flutter.compileSdkVersion`.

I am using Flutter 3.3*. And  I have Android Studio Dolphin (version 4 or higher).

I know I can change it directly as
`compileSdkVersion: 33`. where is it defined? and what is it set to by default ?

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Its where I extracted the `flutter.zip` file.
(at location of  flutter sdk ).

```
flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle
```

WARNING!
its sdk file, so you shouldnt change it from here. Go to `app/gradle` file. change it from there.

Comment: must read the warning.